# How to store state in rxjs observables in an Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to store user status in an Angular service. So I'got a code like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private userName = new BehaviorSubject<string>('undefined');
  private userLoggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  public UserName = this.userName.asObservable();
  public UserLoggedIn = this.userLoggedIn.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  signOut() {
    this.userLoggedIn.next(false);
    this.userName.next('undefined');
  }

  signIn(name) {
    this.userLoggedIn.next(true);
    this.userName.next(name);
  }
}
```

It works fine, but seems to reset `userName` and `userLoggedIn` values each time a page refreshes. So it doest't store anything like, f.e. Redux does.

I think, I've made a mistake somewhere, but can't get what I'm doing wrong - it's my first Angular app((

Comment: How to you provide UserService? only in your AppModule so it's a singleton service? or within each component? If you are providing it in each component, then that component has it's own instance of UserService.

Comment: How do you provide*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use BehaviorSubject which is similar to the Observer pattern and therefore often used to facilitate communication between separate components. It cannot keep data after refreshing the page unless you store your user status in local storage as follows:

Store user status in local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('userStatus', JSON.stringify(userStatus));
```

Get user status from local storage:

```
let userStatus = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userStatus'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on @HT89s answer, you could store the status in the browser so that it is preserved between page refreshes.

```
constructor() {

   // store in the browser each time a value is emitted to userLoggedIn
   this.userLoggedIn
      .do((loggedIn) => {
         localStorage.setItem('userLoggedIn', loggedIn);
      });

   this.userName
      .do((userName) => {
         localStorage.setItem('userName', userName);
      });
}
```

But you would also probably want to extend this kind of solution so that there is some sort of check for expiry of the login.